# SAS hierarchical structure sum

Tags: sql, sas, sum, hierarchy, recursive-query

I have a dataset with a hierarchical codelist variable.
The logics of hierarchy is determined by the LEVEL variable and the prefix structure of the CODE character variable.
There are 6 (code length from 1 to 6) "aggregate" levels and the terminal level (code length of 10 characters).

I need to update the nodes variable (count of terminal nodes - the aggregate levels do not count in the "higher" aggregates, only the terminal nodes) - so the sum of counts in one level, for example every level 5's total count is the same as every level 6's.
And I need to calculate (sum up) the weight to "higher" level nodes.

NOTE: I offset the output table's NODES and WEIGHT variable so you can see better what I am talking about (just add up the numbers in each offset and you get the same value).

EDIT1: there can be multiple observations with the same code. A unique observations is a combination of 3 variables code + var1 + var2.

Input table:

```
ID   level code         var1  var2  nodes  weight  myIndex
1    1     1            .     .     999    999     999
2    2     11           .     .     999    999     999
3    3     111          .     .     999    999     999
4    4     1111         .     .     999    999     999
5    5     11111        .     .     999    999     999
6    6     111111       .     .     999    999     999
7   10     1111119999   01    1     1      0.1     105,5
8   10     1111119999   01    2     1      0.1     109,1
9    6     111112       .     .     999    999     999
10  10     1111120000   01    1     1      0.5      95,0
11   5     11119        .     .     999    999     999
12   6     111190       .     .     999    999     999
13  10     1111901000   01    1     1      0.1      80,7
14  10     1111901000   02    1     1      0.2     105,5
```

Desired output table:

```
ID   level code         var1  var2  nodes    weight              myIndex
1    1     1            .     .     5        1.0                  98,1
2    2     11           .     .     5        1.0                  98,1
3    3     111          .     .     5        1.0                  98,1
4    4     1111         .     .     5        1.0                  98,1
5    5     11111        .     .       3          0.7              98,5
6    6     111111       .     .         2            0.2         107,3
7   10     1111119999   01    1           1               0.1    105,5  
8   10     1111119999   01    2           1               0.1    109,1
9    6     111112       .     .         1            0.5          95,0
10  10     1111120000   01    1           1               0.5     95,0
11   5     11119        .     .       2          0.3              97,2
12   6     111190       .     .         2            0.3          97,2
13  10     1111901000   01    1           1               0.1     80,7
14  10     1111901000   02    1           1               0.2    105,5
```

And here's the code I came up with. It works just like I wanted, but man, it is really slow. I need something way faster, because this is a part of a webservice which has to run "instantly" on request.
Any suggestions on speeding up the code, or any other solutions are welcome.

```
%macro doit;

data temporary;
    set have;
run;

%do i=6 %to 2 %by -1;
    %if &i = 6 %then %let x = 10;
    %else %let x = (&i+1);

    proc sql noprint;
        select count(code)
        into :cc trimmed
        from have
        where level = &i;

        select code
        into :id1 - :id&cc
        from have
        where level = &i;
    quit;

    %do j=1 %to &cc.;

        %let idd = &&id&j;

        proc sql;
        update have t1
            set nodes = (
                       select sum(nodes)
                       from temporary t2
                       where t2.level = &x and t2.code like ("&idd" || "%")),
            set weight = (
                       select sum(weight)
                       from temporary t2
                       where t2.level = &x and t2.code like ("&idd" || "%"))   
            where (t1.level = &i and t1.code like "&idd");
        quit;
    %end;
%end;
%mend doit;
```

Current code based on @Quentin's solution:

```
data have;
input ID level code : $10. nodes weight myIndex;
cards;
1    1  1            .   .    .
2    2  11           .   .    .
3    3  111          .   .    .
4    4  1111         .   .    .
5    5  11111        .   .    .
6    6  111111       .   .    .
7   10  1111110000   1   0.1  105.5
8   10  1111119999   1   0.1  109.1
9    6  111112       .   .    .
10  10  1111129999   1   0.5  95.0
11   5  11119        .   .    .
12   6  111190       .   .    .
13  10  1111900000   1   0.1  80.7
14  10  1111901000   1   0.2  105.5
;

data want (drop=_:);

    *hash table of terminal nodes;
    if (_n_ = 1) then do;
        if (0) then set have (rename=(code=_code weight=_weight));
        declare hash h(dataset:'have(where=(level=10) rename=(code=_code weight=_weight myIndex=_myIndex))');
        declare hiter iter('h');
        h.definekey('ID');
        h.definedata('_code','_weight','_myIndex');
        h.definedone();
    end;

    set have;

    *for each non-terminal node, iterate through;
    *hash table of all terminal nodes, looking for children;
    if level ne 10 then do;
        call missing(weight, nodes, myIndex);

        do _n_ = iter.first() by 0 while (_n_ = 0);
            if trim(code) =: _code then do;  
                weight=sum(weight,_weight);
                nodes=sum(nodes,1);
                myIndex=sum(myIndex,_myIndex*_weight);
            end;
            _n_ = iter.next();
        end;
        myIndex=round(myIndex/weight,.1);
    end;
    output;
run;
```

Comment: How big is the real data? I'm thinking about some ugly brute force methods.

Comment: What do you mean by 'add the numbers in each offset'? Could you use a multilevel format here?

Comment: @Quentin the real data is dynamically changing, but always between 4-5000 observations, so it is not really big.

Comment: @Reeza I was just trying to better explain/visualize what I am trying to achieve with that offset thing. The missalingned/offseted values are from the same hierarchy level, so you can see better, that it always add up to the same number (weight or node count).
I am not aware of how multilevel formats work, but will check it out.

Comment: Your working code references a variable DA6540 which doesn't exist in your sample data.

Comment: Suggest updating your sample data to make an example where two records have same value for code, and change the (null) values to something like 99.

Comment: Approximately how many terminal nodes are there? I think that will end up driving the number of computations needed, at least in the approach that I am thinking.

Comment: @Quentin thanks, de DA6540 is the "level" variable, I simplified the variable names for the purpose of posting it here, but forgot to change it. Changed the sample dataset also.

Comment: ~~3700 terminal nodes, 500 "6length" nodes, 300 "5length" nodes, the rest ~~100 is 2/3/4length nodes and obviously there's only 1 "1length" node.

Comment: So `nodes` should contain the number of *direct* child nodes? And `weight` the sum of *direct* child nodes's weights?

Comment: @joop that's right - only the direct child nodes. That's why all the sums for each level add up to the same number.

Comment: But if I get the sums for all the 6-length nodes, then there's no more need for calculating the "higher" hierarchy nodes from the terminal nodes, because they can be summed up from the 6-length node values.

Comment: Well the "trick" is : add a parent_id field to every record (containing the id of the *direct* parent, obviously) Then: update the records from the COUNT() and SUM() of the child-records, *upward*. In SAS, this may involve (reversed) topological sorting (children before their parent)

Comment: @joop could you please write in a little more detailed form (you don't have to write the code, just in words) how to achieve this?

Comment: The hard part is: finding the *direct* parent. The direct parent is (the id of) the record whose `code` is a substring from our `code` and no other record with a longer code (but still a substring of our code) exists. In your example, `code` is not unique, but the duplicates only occur as siblings at the leaf nodes, so that wont create DAGs. Now, bubble up from the leafs to the root(s) set every record's count,sum to the COUNT(), SUM() of their children. With an adequate amount of topological sorting, my guess is this could be done with `retain` in SAS.

Comment: I think the fastest solution would be to reorganize this into a nested set model then perform an SQL statement to summarize the data.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model .  It's basically a technique that spends time up front re-arranging hierarchical data in order to make it very simple and fast to query via SQL.  We used to do this to identify bottlenecks in supply chain optimizations and it worked very well.  If the input tables are relatively static you could find additional ways to optimize via caching etc...

Comment: Interesting @Robert. If you have the time, would love to see the nested set model solution to the sample data.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions and answers. Will test them out right in the morning (CET).

Comment: @Quentin, user667489 the average CPU time of Quentin's solution is 6,84sec compared to 0,82sec of user667489's approach. That is some -88% cpu time improvement. The absolute real times are almost identical with a -88% relative improvement aswell.
Tom's approach took more than half a minute. I am quite impressed by the speed of hash table lookups.

Comment: That is an impressive difference. Feel free to unaccept my answer and mark @user668489's as correct, assuming it's giving you the correct results and is much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative hash approach.

Rather than using a hash object to do a cartesian join, this adds the nodes & weight from each level 10 node to each of the 6 applicable parent nodes as it goes along. This may be marginally faster than Quentin's approach as there are no redundant hash lookups.

It takes a bit longer than Quentin's approach when constructing the hash object, and uses a bit more memory, as each terminal node is added 6 times with different keys and existing entries often have to be updated, but afterwards each parent node only has to look up its own individual stats, rather than looping through all the terminal nodes, which is a substantial saving.

Weighted stats are possible as well, but you have to update both loops, not just the second one.

```
data want;
if 0 then set have;
dcl hash h();
h.definekey('code');
h.definedata('nodes','weight','myIndex');
h.definedone();
length t_code $10;
do until(eof);
  set have(where = (level = 10)) end = eof;
  t_nodes = nodes;
  t_weight = weight;
  t_myindex = weight * myIndex;
  do _n_ = 1 to 6;
    t_code = substr(code,1,_n_);
    if h.find(key:t_code) ne 0 then h.add(key:t_code,data:t_nodes,data:t_weight,data:t_myIndex);
    else do;
      nodes + t_nodes;
      weight + t_weight;
      myIndex + t_myIndex;
      h.replace(key:t_code,data:nodes,data:weight,data:MyIndex);
    end;
  end;
end;
do until(eof2);
  set have end = eof2;
  if level ne 10 then do;
    h.find();
    myIndex = round(MyIndex / Weight,0.1);
  end;
  output;
end;
drop t_:;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @user667489, will try it out on my exact dataset and let you know how it compares in cpu time to the previously accepted Hash solution.

Comment: Definitely looks promising. @Martin, please let us know how they compare for both CPU time and Real Time. Also curious how Tom's SQL solution compares, as it is lovely.

Comment: @user667489 this solution is not marginally, but n-times faster, but I can't get the exact numbers until I figure out how to apply it to the same dataset. I need to implement a weighted average calculation for some of the variables (for the parent nodes) which I explained to Quentin in the comments under his answer. Would it be possible to implement it using this solution aswell?

Comment: value = sum(weight_child*value_child)/sum(weight_child)

Comment: nvm... I think I figured it out. I think I can do it in the second do until loop (eof2). Will write if I fail to get it right.

Comment: @user667489 I'm a failure, I just can't get it right. Could you please help me out with the weighted average calculation?

Comment: @Martin  - please update your question with some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @user667489 Updated the input/output view and added the current *working* version to see what I'm trying to achieve with your solution.

Comment: @Martin working now. The proc summary solution generalises a little more easily to this sort of thing.

Comment: @user667489 Thanks, I will look into it tomorrow morning. Our Oracle DB (where from I am pulling all the data) is currently undergoing some overnight maintenance and is down ATM so I can't try it out on real data.

Comment: Status update under the original question post. Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: Which solution did you go with in the end?

Comment: I went with your hash solution. It is blazing fast.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a brute-force hash approach to doing a similar Cartesian product as in the SQL.  Load a hash table of the terminal nodes.  Then read through the dataset of nodes, and for each node that is not a terminal node, iterate through the hash table, identifying all of the child terminal nodes.

I think the approach @joop is describing may be more efficient, as this approach doesn't take advantage of the tree structure.  So there is a lot of re-calculating.  With 5000 records and 3000 terminal nodes, this would do 2000*3000 comparisons.  But might not be that slow since the hash table is in memory, so you're not going to have excessive I/O ....

```
data want (drop=_:);

   *hash table of terminal nodes;
   if (_n_ = 1) then do;
      if (0) then set have (rename=(code=_code weight=_weight));
      declare hash h(dataset:'have(where=(level=10) rename=(code=_code weight=_weight))');
      declare hiter iter('h');
      h.definekey('ID');
      h.definedata('_code','_weight');
      h.definedone();
   end;

   set have;

   *for each non-terminal node, iterate through;
   *hash table of all terminal nodes, looking for children;
   if level ne 10 then do;
      call missing(weight, nodes);

      do _n_ = iter.first() by 0 while (_n_ = 0);
         if trim(code) =: _code then do;  
           weight=sum(weight,_weight);
           nodes=sum(nodes,1);
         end;
         _n_ = iter.next();
      end;
   end;
   output;
run;
```

Comment: @martin: if the hash is intimidating I could take a shot at an array solution using the same approach. Load the terminal nodes into an array, read the nodes and search the array, rather than searching a hash table. Let me know if that sounds useful.

Comment: I am marking your answer as a solution. Your hash table approach is way faster than mine code, in the future I will try out joop's solution aswell, but for now I will just stick to this one.
One more question: I am trying to calculate one more variable a weighted average. value = sum(weight_child*value_child)/sum(weight_child). The logics is the same as before, It needs to be calculated for every non-terminal_node from their children terminal_nodes. Is it possible with the same approach?

Comment: I´m thinking of just doing value=sum(value, _value * _weight) and weight=sum(weight, _weight) and at the end of the iteration for that particular parent node just dividing value by weight.

Comment: Agree @Martin, sounds like correct approach for weighted avg in this setting.

Comment: Everything works perfectly and I learned about a new SAS technique (Hashes) - I'm going to dig into this topic, because I think it might help me optimize some other SAS programs aswell.
Thanks @Quentin. I really do appreciate your help. Marked as a solution. Have a nice day, sir.

Comment: Glad it's working! I've never tried analysis of node data before, so it was an interesting problem that I learned from as well!

Comment: I have added [another hash-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44119220/667489) that avoids the redundant hash lookups that result from the cartesian loop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty simple. Just join back with itself and count/sum.

```
proc sql ;
create table want as
 select a.id, a.level, a.code , a.var1, a.var2
      , count(b.id) as nodes
      , sum(b.weight) as weight
 from have a
 left join have b
 on a.code eqt b.code
 and b.level=10
 group by 1,2,3,4,5
 order by 1
;
quit;
```

If you don't want to use the `EQT` operator then you can use the SUBSTR() function instead.

```
 on a.code = substr(b.code,1,a.level)
 and b.level=10
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. Your approach is also working, but the hash table solution is faster on my exact dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using SAS, how about using `proc summary` to do the heavy lifting here? No cartesian joins required!

One advantage of this option over the some of the others is that it's a bit easier to generalise if you want to calculate lots of more complex statistics for multiple variables.

```
data have;
input ID level code : $10. nodes weight myIndex;
format myIndex 5.1;
cards;
1    1  1            .   .    .
2    2  11           .   .    .
3    3  111          .   .    .
4    4  1111         .   .    .
5    5  11111        .   .    .
6    6  111111       .   .    .
7   10  1111110000   1   0.1  105.5
8   10  1111119999   1   0.1  109.1
9    6  111112       .   .    .
10  10  1111129999   1   0.5  95.0
11   5  11119        .   .    .
12   6  111190       .   .    .
13  10  1111900000   1   0.1  80.7
14  10  1111901000   1   0.2  105.5
;
run;


data v_have /view = v_have;
  set have(where = (level = 10));
  array lvl[6] $6;
  do i = 1 to 6;
    lvl[i]=substr(code,1,i);
  end;
  drop i;
run;

proc summary data = v_have;
  class lvl1-lvl6;
  var nodes weight;
  var myIndex /weight = weight;
  ways 1;
  output out = summary(drop = _:) sum(nodes weight)= mean(myIndex)=;
run;

data v_summary /view = v_summary;
  set summary;
  length code $10;
  code = cats(of lvl:);
  drop lvl:;
run;

data have;
  modify have v_summary;
  by code;
  replace;
run;
```

In theory a hash of hashes might also be an appropriate data structure, but that would be extremely complicated for a relatively small benefit. I might have a go anyway just as a learning exercise...

Comment: I am a SAS newbie and I use it in more like a data-manipulation-way rather than a data-analysis-ways. Haven't used proc summary yet, but will check out the documentation. I like this solution aswell. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One approach (I think) would be to make the Cartesian product, and find all of the terminal nodes that are a "match" to each of the nodes, then sum the weights.

Something like:

```
data have;
  input ID level code : $10. nodes weight ;
  cards;
1    1  1            .   .
2    2  11           .   .
3    3  111          .   .
4    4  1111         .   .
5    5  11111        .   .
6    6  111111       .   .
7   10  1111110000   1   0.1
8   10  1111119999   1   0.1
9    6  111112       .   .
10  10  1111129999   1   0.5
11   5  11119        .   .
12   6  111190       .   .
13  10  1111900000   1   0.1
14  10  1111901000   1   0.2
;


proc sql;
  select min(id) as id
       , min(level) as level 
       , a.code
       , count(b.weight) as nodes   /*count of terminal nodes*/
       , sum(b.weight) as weight    /*sum of weights of terminal nodes*/
    from 
      have as a 
     ,(select code , weight
       from have
       where level=10   /*selects terminal nodes*/
       ) as b
    where a.code eqt b.code        /*EQT is equivalent to =: */
    group by a.code
  ;
quit;
```

I'm not sure that is correct, but it gives the desired results for the sample data.

Comment: I tried to run it on the real dataset, but It didn't give me the desired solution. I am guessing it's because in the real dataset I do not have null/missing values.
I put the missing values in there, so it's clearly visible what do I want to update, but I guess it wasn't a good idea.
In the real dataset I already have the nodes and weights calculated once, I need to calculate it over and over again because the terminal nodes dynamically change (insert, delete and update weights).

Comment: one more important thing I forgot to mention. There can be multiple observations with the same code. A unique key pair consists of 3 variables in which the code is one of them.

Comment: Updated to use where level=10 to find the terminal nodes. That should work. I think you could just add var1 and var2 to the select statement and SAS will "remerge" for you. Haven't tested this edit.

Comment: I think a hash solution would be faster. Load all the terminal nodes into a hash table. Then for each record in your dataset, read through the hash table, summing the weights of the terminal nodes that "match" (children?)  to each node. It's the same Cartesian product idea, but using a hash table to do it could be faster than the SQL approach.

Comment: If there can be two terminal records with the same value for code, I think above won't work, because it will assign sum(weight) to both of them. I will try to post a hash approach within next 18 hours.

Comment: Yes I have already modified your SQL code before your response and unfortunately it is doing exactly like you said. It assign the sum(weight) to both.
I am not aware of using hash objects, but already started to study the manual. I would really appreciate some help though. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The SQL approach is barely usable, since SAS's PROC SQL doesn't allow recursive queries, nor window functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL needed to estimate the parent record for every record. It only uses string functions (position and length) so it should be adaptable to any dialect of SQL, maybe even SAS. (the CTE might need to be rewritten to subqueries or a view) The idea is to:

- add a parent_id field to the dataset
- find the record with the longest substring of code
- and use its id as the value for our parent_id
- (after that) update the records from the sum(nodes),sum(weight) of their *direct* children (the ones with child.parent_id = this.id )

BTW: I could have used the `LEVEL` instead of the `LENGTH(code)` ; the data is a bit redundant in this aspect.

---

```
WITH sub AS (
        SELECT id, length(code) AS len
        , code
        FROM tree)
UPDATE tree t
SET parent_id = s.id
FROM sub s
WHERE length(t.code) > s.len AND POSITION (s.code IN t.code) = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sub nx
        WHERE nx.len > s.len AND POSITION (nx.code IN t.code ) = 1
        AND nx.len < length(t.code) AND POSITION (nx.code IN t.code ) = 1
        )
        ;

SELECT * FROM tree
ORDER BY parent_id DESC NULLS LAST
        , id
        ;
```

---

After finding the parents, the whole table should be updated (repeatedly) from itself
like:

---

```
-- PREPARE omg( integer) AS
UPDATE tree  t
SET nodes = s.nodes ,  weight = s.weight
FROM ( SELECT parent_id , SUM(nodes) AS nodes , SUM(weight) AS weight
        FROM tree GROUP BY parent_id) s
WHERE s.parent_id = t.id
        ;
```

---

In SAS, this could probably be done by sorting on {0-parent_id, id} and do some retain+summation magic. (my SAS is a bit rusty in this area)

---

UPDATE: if only the leaf nodes have non-NULL (non-missing) values for {nodes, weight}, the aggregation can be done in one sweep for the entire tree, without first computing the parent_ids:

```
UPDATE tree  t
SET nodes = s.nodes ,  weight = s.weight
FROM ( SELECT p.id , SUM(c.nodes) AS nodes , SUM(c.weight) AS weight
        FROM tree p
        JOIN tree c ON c.lev > p.lev AND POSITION (p.code IN c.code ) = 1
        GROUP BY p.id
        ) s
WHERE s.id = t.id
        ;
```

---

An index on `{lev,code}` will probably speed up things. (assuming an index on id)

Comment: Thanks @joop. I will look into this solution aswell, because later I will be doing some code optimization. For now I will just stick to Quentin's solution, because I need to test the whole system if it's working or not.